# C++ compilation clang error multiple output files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang

I can't figure out why i can't compile my program with

```
    g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp Sale.h iProduct.h -o w7
```

every time i try and compile with this command i get a clang error

```
    clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

the program complies fine as a.out and i know i could just rename the a.out file and be on my way but i would like to know why I'm getting this error and how i should fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Don't specify .h files in the command line. Just `g++ -Wall -std=c++0x main.cpp -o w7` is all you need.

Comment: Thank you @PaulR that worked, may I ask why do the .h files affect it?

Comment: Header files (.h suffix) are typically intended to be #included by .cpp files, so they don't need to be compiled separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why I'm getting this error and how i should fix it
>   may I ask why do the .h files affect it?

Because of recent versions of `gcc` can compile heaader files,
Example:

```
g++ test.h -o out
file out
out: GCC precompiled header (version 014) for C++
```

It(`gcc`) produce precompiled files (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) in this case.

So when you compile `.cpp` file and header at the same time,
it can not decide what produce as output precompiled headers, or elf  executable.